# efficient programming in R

Tags: r, loops, stringdist

I have a data like

```
author_id paper_id confirmed     author_name1   author_affiliation1         author_name   
   826    25733         1     Emanuele Buratti  Genetic engineering    Emanuele Buratti
   826    25733         1     Emanuele Buratti  International center   Emanuele Buratti
   826    47276         1     Emanuele Buratti                         Emanuele Buratti
   826    77012         1     Emanuele Buratti                         Emanuele Buratti
   826    77012         1     Emanuele Buratti                         Emanuele Buratti
   826    79468         1     Emanuele Buratti                         Emanuele Buratti

author_affiliation
Genetic enginereing                                                                                                
The International Centre for Genetic Engineering and Biotechnology, Padriciano 66,        
Trieste, Italy


International Centre for Genetic Engineering and Biotechnology, Padriciano 99, 34149                         
Trieste, Italy
```

Now I have to check for each row strindist between author_name and author_name1(name_dist) and the stringdist between author_affiliation vs author_affiliation1(aff_sit.

I am using

```
name_dist<-vector()
aff_dist<-vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(mer1))
{
 name_dist[i]<-stringdist(mer1$author_name1[i],mer1$author_name[i],method="lv")
 aff_dist[i]<-stringdist(mer1$author_affiliation1[i],mer1$author_affiliation[i],method="lv")

 }
```

But this is using a lot of time.How could this be done efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: A general comment on R:  the reason many loops execute slowly is because vectors are dynamically grown.  You can gain a lot of efficiency by preallocating the space which is done by adding a `length` argument to `vector()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly vectorize it

```
i=1:nrow(mer1)
name_dist<-stringdist(mer1$author_name1[i],mer1$author_name[i],method="lv")
aff_dist<-stringdist(mer1$author_affiliation1[i],mer1$author_affiliation[i],method="lv")
```

Comment: This is not completely correct code. You should loose the indices completely.

Comment: @MarkvanderLoo good spot. In this case where we are processing the whole dataset it would be better without the `i` and `[i]`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` (or some other vectorization method), like so:

```
a = letters[1:5] # your mer1$author_name1
b = LETTERS[1:5] # your mer1$author_name
name_dist = sapply(a, stringdist, b, method="lv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
res <- transform(mer1, 
    name_dist=stringdist(author_name1,author_name,method="lv"),
    aff_dist=stringdist(author_affiliation1,author_affiliation,method="lv")
)
```

Since `stringdist` is a function capable of vector input, it should be more efficient this way.